# Changing Bootstrap tooltip content when shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Is there any way to change the content of a Bootstrap tooltip *when the tooltip is showing*?

```
$('.tooltip-inner').html(myContent);
```

is not good enough, since I have a number of tooltips on the page.

Preferably, I'd want the ID of the tooltip div (generated by Bootstrap), but it's changing every time it's shown.

The use-case is a small HTML game, where tooltips are used for showing resources in real-time.

**Edit**: Current solution: Define a variable `toggle`, set it to true when tooltips is shown and false when hidden using the Bootstrap tooltip events. Use `$('.tooltip-content').html(content)` when `toggle` is true.

Comment: What you mean with ID is changing every time it's shown?

Comment: The ID of the tooltip div it self is changing (not the ID of the span which the tooltip belongs to).

Comment: so you can access it through parent or some data-attribute

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the tooltip to update using this:

```
$('#el').attr('data-original-title', 'New text').tooltip();
```

Nothing else I found online helped until I found this post and saw [the answer from divy3993](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43606212/810607), which also didn't work, but got me close enough to figure out what would.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to change `title` attribute before `tooltip` show up.

Check below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newValue = "This does change huh..";
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr('title', newValue).tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, maybe I need to clarify. The tooltip content will be changing every second, even when shown (because resources in the game are increased/decreased).

Comment: Ok, so how does it change? I mean what does it change on? On Time Interval?

Comment: Yeah, there's a tick in the game I hook into.

Comment: Ok, so do you have some binding to specific/respective tooltip with that tick? If so, then how?

Comment: You can not rely on the `tooltip ID`of bootstrap, you need something to bind that tick and tooltip group in your game.